# How to measure the graph edit distance by considering the node names

Tags: python-3.x, networkx

I have defined two Graphs in python using the library networkx and now I want to measure the distance between those two graphs considering the nodes' "names"

I created two Graphs, looking totally the same (tree graphs)

```py
G=nx.Graph()
G.add_edges_from([("A","B"),("A","C")])

H=nx.Graph()
H.add_edges_from([("X","Y"),("X","Z")])

res=nx.graph_edit_distance(G,H)
res2=nx.optimize_edit_paths(G,H)
res3=nx.optimal_edit_paths(G,H)
```

I want all nodes to be replaced, because the nodes don't have the same name, but I get the result for the cost (changes/ distance) 0. This means that the function is not considering the nodes' names.

In the [documentation](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/latest/reference/algorithms/generated/networkx.algorithms.similarity.optimal_edit_paths.html) it is suggested to use the function "node_math" but I don't know how to use it. It does not seem to be a networkx function.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The reason it is giving the answer as `0` is because it is considering the nodes to be equal. If you see the documentation, it mentions that that

> node_match (callable) – A function that returns True if node n1 in G1
>   and n2 in G2 should be considered equal during matching.
>
> The function will be called like
>
> ```
> node_match(G1.nodes[n1], G2.nodes[n2]).
> ```
>
> That is, the function will receive the node attribute dictionaries for
>   n1 and n2 as inputs.

Now, since you have not declared any attributes, then in that case

```
G.nodes['A'] will return {}
```

and

```
H.nodes['Z'] will return {}
```

Now since both are empty dictionaries, they will be considered equal.

Here is modified version of your code, where I have added a labels attribute for your node.

```
import networkx as nx

G=nx.Graph()
G.add_nodes_from([("A", {'label':'a'}), ("B", {'label':'b'}),
                  ("C", {'label':'c'})])

G.add_edges_from([("A","B"),("A","C")])

H=nx.Graph()
H.add_nodes_from([("X", {'label':'x'}), ("Y", {'label':'y'}),
                  ("Z", {'label':'z'})])
H.add_edges_from([("X","Y"),("X","Z")])

# This is the function which checks for equality of labels
def return_eq(node1, node2):
    return node1['label']==node2['label']

print(nx.graph_edit_distance(G, H, node_match=return_eq))
# Output: 3
```